# Windows Firewall Remote Address Ranges

Tags: windows, active-directory, firewall, windows-firewall

I am trying to enable Remote Desktop access to my Windows 20102 servers and Windows 10 workstations after connecting to our network via VPN.  I couldn't connect though and I found that a number of the Windows Firewall rules have specific Remote Address ranges that match up to the IP address ranges for our main network and our branch office network.  This works fine when at work but when I connect from home, I am given an IP address from the VPN network range - which is obviously excluded from the firewall rules.  Now, my question is how did these ranges get set on the firewall rules?  I don't think I set them so I'm wondering if it's done automatically from, say, Active Directory sites?  If so, can I add a site for the VPN network and have the rules update automatically?  I really don't want to have to create custom GPO to add the VPN range to all of the rules?

Comment: It's not done automatically. It's done via Group Policy. So the administrators of the Windows domain have done that. You'll need to speak to them to get the VPN ranges added.

Answer (score 0):

As per @joequerty, I looked more deeply at our GPOs and found the offending IP ranges.  The problem was that GPOs have firewall settings in both "Computer Config/Policies/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" and "Computer Config/Admin Templates/Network/Network Connections/Windows Firewall".  My IP address ranges were in the latter section.